# How to deal with definite integrals more vividly

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{2R}\left(\int_{-\arccos\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)}^{\arccos\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)}rd\theta\right)dr$$

I can use $\int_{-\arccos\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)}^{\arccos\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)}rd\theta$ as the arc length,The next step is to integrate $0$ to $R$. This can be interpreted as the area of a circle made up of countless arc lengths.

But when I change the order of integration.Such as:
$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\int_{0}^{2R\cos(\theta)}rdr\right)d\theta$.

Question 1：I can't seem to imagine what rdr($\int_{0}^{2R\cos(\theta)}rdr$) is. It seems unimaginable, just the values are equal?Can someone tell me what this can represent in an imaginary way.

Question 2:How can we avoid missing something in the integration, can you explain it briefly?How do you know whether this approach is completely correct.

$Explanation:$

Before integrating the sector area,I put $d\theta$ as a constant.This can be written $\int_{0}^{2R\cos(\theta)}rd\theta dr$,$rd\theta dr$ can be regarded as part of the sector area,Now I will integrate on 0 to 2R,In the end this is a sector area about an angle $d\theta$.The last step I need to integrate between $-pi/2$ and $pi/2$,Countless sectors area fill this circle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvUuN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6wcF.png)

Comment: It’s the area under the graph of $y= x$ from $0$ to $2R\cos\theta$.

Comment: I don’t know if you still struggle with this problem！Let me explain the second formula,I cannot remove $d\theta$ alone before integration,Take it as a constant.$rd\{theta}dr$，Integration between 0 and 2R.This is a very small sector area about an angle $d\theta$.

Comment: Finally, I integrate the angles. At this time, $d\theta$ is used as an integral variable,This step is about the integration of infinitesimal sector area.